# Barchart (o plot) 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-3d

I need to plot some data in various forms. Currently I'm using [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) and I'm fairly happy with the plots I'm able to produce.

This question is on how to plot the last one. The data is similar to the "distance table", like [this](http://www.southernct.edu/wellness/uploads/textWidget/wysiwyg/documents/Campus_Walking_Map__Distance_Chart.pdf) (just bigger, my table is 128x128 and still have 3 or more number per element).

Now, my data is much better "structured" than a distance table (my data doesn't varies "randomly" like in a alphabetically sorted distance table), thus a 3D [barchart](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/BarCharts), or maybe 3 of them, would be perfect. My understanding is that such a chart is missing in Matplotlib.

I could use a (colored) Countor3d like [these](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/mplot3D) or something in 2D like imshow, but it isn't really well representative of what the data is (the data has meaning just in my 128 points, there isn't anything between two points). And the height of bars is more readable than color, IMO.

Thus the questions:

1. is it possible to create 3D barchart in Matplotlib? It should be clear that I mean with a 2D domain, not just a 2D barchart with a "fake" 3D rendering for aesthetics purposes
2. if the answer to the previous question is no, then is there some other library able to do that? I strongly prefer something Python-based, but I'm OK with other Linux-friendly possibilities
3. if the answer to the previous question is no, then do you have any suggestions on how to show that data? E.g. create a table with the values, superimposed to the imshow or other colored way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MyavaVi2](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/) can make [3D barcharts](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/mlab.html#d-data) (scroll down a bit).  Once you have [MayaVi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MayaVi)/[VTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTK)/[ETS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthought)/etc. installed it all works beautifully, but it can be some work getting it all installed.  Ubuntu has all of it packaged, but they're the only Linux distribution I know that does.

Comment: Looks good an it is a piece of cake to install in Ubuntu, just 
sudo apt-get install mayavi2

Unfortunately that example don't work:

from enthought.mayavi.mlab import *
ImportError: No module named mlab

while (suggestion found online)
from enthought.mayavi.tools.mlab import *

works, but don't provide barchart()

Suggestions?

Comment: what version of mayavi2 do you have?  i believe mlab was overhauled for the 3.1.0 release, and that's what the documentation is covering.

Comment: "mayavi2 -V" gives "MayaVi 2.0.2a1"

Comment: you're on hardy?  according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=mayavi2 you might need jaunty to get a version of mayavi2 that's new enough to have barchart included.  how hard it is to backport a package?

Comment: No I cannot use it, but I'm marking your answer as accepted since you pointed out a very nice tool that I didn't know

Comment: What about easy_install mayavi?

Answer (score 7):

For some time now, matplotlib had no 3D support, but it has been added back [recently](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.devel/6762/focus=6820). You will need to use the svn version, since no release has been made since, and the documentation is a little sparse (see examples/mplot3d/demo.py). I don't know if mplot3d supports real 3D bar charts, but one of the demos looks a little like it could be extended to something like that.

Edit: The source code for the demo is in [the examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/demo.html) but for some reason the result is not. I mean the `test_polys` function, and here's how it looks like:

[example figure http://www.iki.fi/jks/tmp/poly3d.png](http://www.iki.fi/jks/tmp/poly3d.png)

The `test_bar2D` function would be even better, but it's commented out in the demo as it causes an error with the current svn version. Might be some trivial problem, or something that's harder to fix.

Comment: Can the demo result be seen somewhere online? If not, can you run it on your local machine and edit your answer to show the source code and the resulting picture?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not accepting your answer since it doesn't work right now, but I upvoted it, and I look forward to see it working

Answer (score 5):

One more possibility is Gnuplot, which can draw some kind of [pseudo 3D bar charts](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plotpm3d-e.html#6.9), and [gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) allows interfacing to Gnuplot from Python. I have not tried it myself, though.

Comment: +1 Wow, gnuplot is coming from the back door in python :-) I used it a lot in the 90s... I'll have a look at it (but the pseudo 3D bar charts are ugly, compared to the newer tools...)

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for a simple Bar-3d using matplotlib.

```
import mpl_toolkits
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

## The value you want to plot 
zval=[0.020752244,0.078514652,0.170302899,0.29543857,0.45358061,0.021255922,0.079022499,\
  0.171294169,0.29749654,0.457114286,0.020009631,0.073154019,0.158043498,0.273889264,0.419618287]    

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
col=["#ccebc5","#b3cde3","#fbb4ae"]*5
xpos=[1,2,3]*5
ypos=range(1,6,1)*5
zpos=[0]*15
dx=[0.4]*15
dy=[0.5]*15
dz=zval

for i in range(0,15,1):
     ax.bar3d(ypos[i], xpos[i], zpos[i], dx[i], dy[i], dz[i],     
color=col[i],alpha=0.75)

ax.view_init(azim=120)
plt.show()
```

http://i8.tietuku.com/ea79b55837914ab2.png

Comment: A little late to the party (I don't even remember what I was trying to plot back then!) but nice to see this feature finally implemented in matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

You might check out Chart Director:

> http://www.advsofteng.com

It has a pretty wide variety of charts and graphs and has a nice Python (and several other languages) API.

There are two editions: The free version puts a blurb on the generated image, and the
pay version is pretty reasonably priced.

Here's one of the more interesting looking 3d stacked bar charts:

[image: sample graph]
<sub>(source: [advsofteng.com](http://www.advsofteng.com/images/demo10.png))</sub>